# .jade files update html files, but browser-sync refreshes too early

Tags: gulp, pug, browser-sync

I've been ponding on this for hours now, I'd love a tip to get my setup going.

Whenever I save my .jade files, the browser does not update immediately. Instead, I need to save a second time before updates are reflected in the browser: the webserver refreshes prior to completing the build-jade task. This seems weird, as I do have the 'build-jade' task as a dependency prior to refreshing.

The .html file is updated after the first save, it's just the refresh occuring too early.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

gulp-file:

```
/*global require*/
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  path = require('path'),
  data = require('gulp-data'),
  jade = require('gulp-jade'),
  prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync');


/*
 * Change directories here
 */

var public_dir = "dist/"
var settings = {
  sass_files: "applications/**/*.sass",
  jade_files: "applications/**/*.jade",
  js_files: "applications/**/*.js"
};



/**
 * Compile .scss files into public css directory With autoprefixer no
 * need for vendor prefixes then live reload the browser.
 */
gulp.task('build-sass', function() {
  gulp.src(settings.sass_files)
  // gulp.src(settings.sass_files, { base: "./" })
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      onError: browserSync.notify
    }))
    .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(public_dir))
    // .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});


/**
 * Compile .jade files and pass in data from json file
 * matching file name. index.jade - index.jade.json
 */
gulp.task('build-jade', function() {
  gulp.src(settings.jade_files)
  // gulp.src(settings.jade_files, { base: "./" })
    .pipe(jade({ pretty: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(public_dir));
});

/**
 * Recompile .jade files and live reload the browser
 */
gulp.task('jade-rebuild', ['build-jade'], function() {
  browserSync.reload();
});


/**
 * Wait for jade and sass tasks, then launch the browser-sync Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['build-sass', 'build-jade'], function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {baseDir: public_dir},
    notify: true
  });
});


/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch .jade files run jade-rebuild then reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  // gulp.watch(settings.js_files, ['jade-rebuild']);
  gulp.watch(settings.sass_files, ['build-sass']);
  gulp.watch(settings.jade_files, ['jade-rebuild']);
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync then watch
 * files for changes
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you do have the task in the dependancy list, you are not returning the task, so gulp doesn't actually know when it finishes, fortunately this is quite a simple thing to rectify.

I have taken a sample of your code and added `return` to the `gulp.src()` function, you need to follow this procedure with all your functions and then it will work.

Hopefully this is clear enough for you to move forward.

```
/**
 * Compile .jade files and pass in data from json file
 * matching file name. index.jade - index.jade.json
 */
gulp.task('build-jade', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.jade_files)
  // gulp.src(settings.jade_files, { base: "./" })
    .pipe(jade({ pretty: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(public_dir));
});
```

Let me know if i can be of any additional help.

Comment: I wish I could give more than one thumbs up, thanks a bunch! I'll be posting some more issues in my workflow soon, I'd practically marry you if you could get me going towards  coding actual things rather than a workflow soon!

Comment: Slowly getting there, wish I could speed it up though. I've added my other issues on here as well, would appreciate a brief review/tips for getting there ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779589/how-to-import-customize-bundle-jspm-modules-shared-assets-for-multiple-mi